# calculating dataframe row combinations and matches with a separate column

Tags: r

I am trying to match all combinations of a dataframe (each combination reduces to a 1 or a 0 based on the sum) to another column and count the matches. I hacked this together but I feel like there is a better solution. Can someone suggest a better way to do this?

```
library(HapEstXXR)
test<-data.frame(a=c(0,1,0,1),b=c(1,1,1,1),c=c(0,1,0,1))
actual<-c(0,1,1,1)

ps<-powerset(1:dim(test)[2])
lapply(ps,function(x){
    tt<-rowSums(test[,c(x)]) #Note: this fails when there is only one column
    tt[tt>1]<-1 #if the sum is greater than 1 reduce it to 1
    cbind(sum(tt==actual,na.rm=T),colnames(test)[x])
})

> test
  a b c
1 0 1 0
2 1 1 1
3 0 1 0
4 1 1 1
```

goal: compare all combinations of columns (order doesnt matter) to actual column and see which matches most

```
b c a  ab ac bc abc actual
1 0 0  0  0  0  0      0
1 1 1  1  1  1  1      1
1 0 0  0  0  0  0      1
1 1 1  1  1  1  1      1
```

matches:

```
a: 3
b: 3
c: 3
ab: 3
....
```

Comment: Regarding your Note in the code: do `tt<-rowSums(test[,c(x),drop=F])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems fine to me, I just simplified it a little bit:

```
sapply(ps,function(x){
    tt <- rowSums(test[,x,drop=F]) > 0
    colname <- paste(names(test)[x],collapse='')
    setNames(sum(tt==actual,na.rm=T), colname) # make a named vector of one element length
})

#  a   b  ab   c  ac  bc abc 
#  3   3   3   3   3   3   3
```